# При пропуске припевов, после слова "Припев" какой знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Если в словах песни припев приводится только после первого куплета, а после остальных стоит лишь слово "Припев", то какой знак препинания нужно после этого слова ставить: двоеточие или точку?

Comment: Я бы поставил точку, если это просто отбойник и после него начинается следующий куплет.

Comment: Припев: Текст припева//А потом, разумеется, следующий куплет, затем с новой строки слово "Припев", ТОЧКА. С новой строки текст третьего куплета. //// А если, боже упаси, стоит "Припев:", значит то, что после двоеточия — это новый текст припева (текст, поющийся на мелодию припева)

Answer (score 4):

Двоеточие нужно ставить, если далее приводится сам текст припева.

```
Припев:
текст припева.
```

Если текст припева уже был дан выше, можно его не писать снова, а поставить только слово "Припев." (с точкой), или "Припев 2р.", если текст припева должен повторяться 2 раза.